# magento 2 disable shipping calculation on cart page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

How can i disable shipping calculation on cart page.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You mean to remove the shipping from the cart totals?

Comment: No, cart total is fine, but remove shipping calculation.

Comment: Which shipping methods are you using? You can disable all shipping methods to remove shipping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try below code in this file `app/design/frontend/<YOUR_THEME>/default/layout/local.xml`

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping" />
</checkout_cart_index>
```